# Is a seudah (festive meal) required for a Pidyon Hamor (redemption of a 1st born donkey)?

Tags: meal-seudah

I'm uncertain if a *pidyon hamor* requires a festive meal (I've never been to one), similar to *pidyon haben* (redeeming first born son.) Is there a mitzvah to do one? If it is not a mitzvah, do farmers do it, anyway? What do they serve (lamb chops, maybe?)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, they do not make a seudah.

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef says: For someone who would fulfill this mitzvah, the chamor is redeemed either with a sheep or money of equal value. The money is given to a Kohen, just like in a Pidyon HaBen. Shehechiyanu is not said unless one is wearing a new garment according to Yabia Omer.

Here's [the original wording of the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_61.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2):

> סימן שכא - הלכות פטר חמור
>
> א בכור בהמה טמאה נוהג בכל מקום ובכל זמן. ואינו נוהג אלא בחמורים. וזהו מצותו, שכל ישראל שיש לו חמורה שביכרה פודהו בשה מן הכשבים או מן העזים, בין זכר בין נקבה, ובין שלם בין בעל מום, בין גדול בין קטן, ויתננו לכהן. ומאימתי חייב לפדותו, משיולד עד שימות, אלא שמצוה לפדותו מיד, שלא להשהות המצוה. ולאחר שיפדנו הוא חולין גמורים, ומותר בגיזה ועבודה כשאר חולין. והכהן יעשה גם כן בשה כמו בשאר חולין. [שלחן ערוך יורה דעה סימן שכא סעיף א].‏
>
> ב אם אין לו שה לפדותו, פודהו בשווייו. ונותן דמיו לכהן. לא אמרה תורה להחמיר עליו אלא להקל עליו, שאם היה לו פטר חמור ששוה עשרה סלעים, יש לו לפדותו בשה שוה דינר. במה דברים אמורים כשהיו דמי פטר חמור מג' זוזין ומעלה, אבל אם היו דמיו פחות מג' זוזין, אין פודין אותו אלא בשה או בג' זוזין. ועין יפה לא יפחות מסלע. ועין רעה בחצי סלע, ובינונית בג' זוזים. [שם סעיף ה].‏
>
> ג בענין מצות פטר חמור, המקיים מצוה זו לא יברך שהחיינו, אלא ילבש בגד חדש ויברך ''שהחיינו'' לפוטרו, ויפטור גם את המצוה מברכת שהחיינו. [יבי''א ח''י יו''ד סי' לא עמ' רמו].‏

However, it makes no mention of a meal.

In fact, even in the case of the festive meal for Pidyon HaBachor it is only Minhag Yisrael as found in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, 164:1. See also Sdei Chemed, Ma'arechet HaPeh, K'lal 39.

Comment: While the _KSAYY_ does imply an answer to the question "Is there a mitzvah to do one [meal]?", the second question, "If it is not a mitzvah, do farmers do it, anyway?", remains unanswered AFAICT.